# Problem with ContourPlot3D of a torus

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a torus using the equation of its surface

```
 With[{R = 106, r = 50}, ContourPlot3D[(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] - R)^2 + z^2 == r^2, {x, -(R + r), R + r}, {y, -(R + r), R + r}, {z, -r, r}]]
```

But, but the torus shown is flattened. When I use `{z, -(r + R), r + R}` it works. Why does it not work with the interval from `-r` to `r`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the box ratios:

```
BoxRatios->{1,1,1/3}
```

[image]

Comment: `BoxRatios -> Automatic` works too. (+1)

Comment: Thank you , why this instruction is necessary, i am new at this?

Comment: Your plotting ranges are from -156 to 156 in $x$ and $y$, but only -50 to 50 in $z$.  *Mathematica* makes a default box of ratios 1,1,1 in scale (stretching each axis to fit).  If you want a plot that is thin and flat (for instance), you'll have to change to BoxRatios.  Clear?